# Oracle11g numeric overflow in for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ora-01426

I have a for loop in pl/sql function something like:

```
FOR i IN min..max LOOP
```

variables i, min, max are declared as `NUMERIC`

in my case min and max are ofen very large, but range itself is small, ie:

```
min = 3232236033
max = 3232236286
```

as You see range is about ~256, but with this values oracle throws a numeric overflow error and I stuck on how to get it working.

How I should iterate over those values?

**EDIT**

OK, I have a working answer, using of loop of max/min diff, but is it really not possible to loop through big values in oracle?

**EDIT** The error I retrieve is:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01426: nadmiar numeryczny
ORA-06512: przy "PS.DHCP", linia 88
01426. 00000 -  "numeric overflow"
*Cause:    Evaluation of an value expression causes an overflow/underflow.
*Action:   Reduce the operands.
```

Line 88 of code is:

```
FOR client_ip IN min_host..max_host
```

min_host, max_host, client_ip is a result of `inet_aton` (numeric representation of IP)

Comment: Please show your code along with the exceptions you are receiving

Comment: The function has over 70 lines of code, but I'll paste, the error report

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it seems the problem comes from i being cast as too small a number (which seems to a a fault of pl/sql),
you can change your loop type:

a While loop works fine

```
set serveroutput on
/
declare
 min_val number;
 max_val number ;
 iterator number ;
begin
    min_val := 3232236033 ;
    max_val := 3232236286 ;

    iterator := min_val;
    while iterator<=max_val loop
        dbms_output.put_line(iterator);
        iterator  := iterator  + 1;
    end loop ;

end;
/
```

From here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/controlstatements.htm#BABEFFDC

> FOR LOOP Index
>
> The index of a FOR LOOP statement is
>   implicitly declared as a variable of
>   type INTEGER that is local to the
>   loop. The statements in the loop can
>   read the value of the index, but
>   cannot change it. Statements outside
>   the loop cannot reference the index.
>   After the FOR LOOP statement runs, the
>   index is undefined. (A loop index is
>   sometimes called a loop counter.)
>
> In Example 4-17, the FOR LOOP
>   statement tries to change the value of
>   its index, causing an error.

onwards to this:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/loop_statement.htm

> index_name
>
> An undeclared identifier that names
>   the loop index (sometimes called a
>   loop counter). Its scope is the loop
>   itself; you cannot reference the index
>   outside the loop.
>
> The implicit declaration of index_name
>   overrides any other declaration
>   outside the loop. To refer to another
>   variable with the same name, use a
>   label. See Example 4-22, "Referencing
>   Global Variable with Same Name as Loop
>   Counter".
>
> Inside a loop, the index is treated
>   like a constant: it can appear in
>   expressions, but cannot be assigned a
>   value.

thus even though you declare the "index" in your declare, it is NOT being used within the loop and instead is using the implicitly created INDEX (which seems to have a precision too small for your needs)

Comment: +1. Also believe the Oracle documentation is mistaken when it says "The index of a FOR LOOP statement is implicitly declared as a variable of type INTEGER." `Integer` in Oracle are a synonym for `number(38)` which is plenty big enough. My guess is that the index of a for loop is actually a `pls_integer` which is a 32 bit integer and not big enough for OP's uses. See: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#i10726 for information about `pls_integer`.

Comment: The 11gR1 documenation makes it clear that `pls_integer` is being used: _Internally, PL/SQL assigns the values of the bounds to temporary PLS_INTEGER variables, and, if necessary, rounds the values to the nearest integer. The magnitude range of a PLS_INTEGER is -2147483648 to 2147483647, represented in 32 bits. If a bound evaluates to a number outside that range, you get a numeric overflow error when PL/SQL attempts the assignment. See PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER Data Types._ http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#CIHIIABG.

Comment: cont... It may be that 11gR2 is actually using `integer` now, but I saw no mention in the "What's New" section of the manual. Or the 11gR2 documenation was simplified until it is wrong. I don't have 11gR2 to test on.

Comment: @Shannon Severance, it appears that the first link I provided (which is for 11g Release 2 (11.2)) which states INTEGER is wrong...) I am running 11gr2 and I can attest that the FOR loop that OP had problem with is still having problems in 11gR2.  The second link I provided (11gR1 states PLS_INTEGER clearly).  I concur with your initial assessment that the documentation is incorrect (at least on the first link)

Answer (score 3):

You could run the loop variable from 0 to the difference between `min` and `max`. Here's an example that merely writes the numbers to DBMS_OUTPUT:

```
DECLARE
  v_min     INTEGER := 3232236033;
  v_max     INTEGER := 3232236286;
  v_diff    PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_diff := v_max - v_min;
  FOR i IN 0..v_diff
  LOOP
    -- Use v_min + i where you would have used i.
    dbms_output.put_line(v_min + i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**EDIT**: sadly you can't use the range operator to iterate through large numbers.  The range operator `..` is restricted to the range +/- 2<sup>31</sup>.   From the [PL/SQL documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/04_struc.htm#sthref485):

> Internally, PL/SQL assigns the values of the bounds to temporary PLS_INTEGER variables, and, if necessary, rounds the values to the nearest integer. The magnitude range of a PLS_INTEGER is -2**31 .. 2**31. If a bound evaluates to a number outside that range, you get a numeric overflow error when PL/SQL attempts the assignment.

Comment: Ok, I see that this will work, but I do not understand, why I have to use such a pointless loop complication, is there really no way, to loop through big values in oracle?